# store bits in an integer value in c

Tags: c

Consider an 8-bit complier say Turbo C, in which we have an integer of size, say 2-words i.e. 16-bits or 2 bytes. I need to store three integer values.

Integer 1  | 0-3             | 2bits (00-11 in binary)

Integer 2   | 0-5            | 3bits (000-101 in binary)

Inetger 3   | 0-7            | 3bits (000-111 in binary)

In total, we need only 8 bits to store all of these three values. Which means that a single variable of integer datatype has enough memory to accomodate these values. i need to 
develop a program which can - at the maximum - use only two instances of integer datatype, first one for the purpose of scanning values from the standard input device say keyboard and the second one to store the data entered by user in the form of three integer variables as discussed above and print them by retreving it from the second instance in which the data was stored.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want us to help, then you need to show us that you tried something. Otherwise this will just get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Smells like homework (see and/or/not operators)

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is homework.

Comment: @devnull I don't think homework is off-topic.  It seems reasonable to post a question asking for help so long as you have a go first and post your code with the question.  If I'm wrong, I'd appreciate any links to FAQs etc. which discourage homework questions.

Comment: @simonc the fact that OP didn't demonstrate any attempt to solving the problem was implicit.

Answer (score 2):

use bitfields:

```
union X{
  byte byteval;
  struct {
    byte piece1:3;
    byte piece2:3;
    byte piece3:2;
  } pieces;
};
```

then you have transparent access :

```
X a;
a.pieces.piece2=3;
a.byteval;
```

and don't have to shift left and right...leave it to the compiler ;)

Comment: Don't do other people's homework, they will learn nothing :P

Comment: next time i'll be more careful...but if it's homework for bitwise operators...then my answer is useless ;)